# Link a permalink in an RDF SKOS concept

Tags: rdf, skos

I have created a SKOS concept. This is working fine. Now I want to annotate my concept with some additional information and implement a link to a VIAF authority ID, namely, http://viaf.org/viaf/136631587.

```xml
<skos:Concept rdf:about="localhost/Hollywood">
    <skos:prefLabel>Hollywood</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:altLabel>American studio</skos:altLabel>
    <skos:inScheme rdf:resource="localhost/thesaurus"/>
    <skos:broader rdf:resource="localhost/Film"/>
</skos:Concept>
```

The question is: which Element from the SKOS reference should I use, and how? Is this a working example?

```xml
<skos:exactMatch rdf:resource="http://viaf.org/viaf/136631587"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `skos:exactMatch` relation is used to link two concepts together that are semantically so close that they can be used interchangeably (that is, wherever you use one, you can replace it with the other without changing the meaning). They are, in other words, identical for all intents and purposes.

If you consider your SKOS concept indeed to be such a strong match with the viaf concept to which you link, then yes, `skos:exactMatch` is the correct relation to use. If not, then perhaps a slightly weaker matching relation, like `skos:closeMatch`, might be a better fit.